# Headless Application BlackBerry 10

Tags: triggers, sms, blackberry-10, headless

I am implementing a IM service and I want to include as one of the features the ability to send and receive an sms message. I am wondering if when an SMS message is received (not a ported directed sms, a regular sms) it is possible to wake up the short running headless application. If someone knows how to do this, please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The currently available [headless triggers](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/headless_apps/triggers.html) are:

- receiving a push
- entering a geofence area
- leaving a geofence area
- port-directed sms
- device start
- application update